# Please list code highlighting before bold and italics in Stack Overflow's editing help

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, editing-help

When editing the body of a question, "How to Format" has

```
► put returns between paragraphs 
► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end 
► _italic_ or **bold**
► indent code by 4 spaces
► backtick escapes `like_so_`
► and some other stuff
► please do not ask how to parse XHTML with regular expressions
► or why two floating point numbers aren't equal
```

Some questions on Stack Overflow by new users have bold [used](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1140979/revisions) when backticks should be used instead. If the order of bullet points were changed, they might be more likely to use the correct formatting.

Comment: If it is possible to edit the post that way, they should edit it! Everything that matters is a good format of a question to be made it clear for users to understand and help them!

Answer (score 5):

It actually seems as though the opposite problem exists where many new users <del>ab</del>use backticks for the purpose of highlighting text.

- [Abuse of code formatting to add unnecessary emphasis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165700/209031)
- [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/209031)

As those posts have pointed out, there are a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/283418) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/283447) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/283422)

Regardless, the **How to Format** isn't necessarily a style guide.  It doesn't tell anybody how they *should* use markdown formatting, it just tells them how to *do it*.

Finally, it looks like the markdown help has been changed since creating this post so that *Styling* and *Code* are two different sections that have the appropriate markdown help, thus alleviating any confusion:

[image: Screenshot]