# Why do some editors think using unnecessary code formatting "enhances readability?"

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)

I am only asking this question because I've seen this several times now, take the [following edit for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/301447). It uses code formatting on several words to "enhance readability."

Am I missing something here or are edits like this completely invalid? Does the idea of `enhancing readability` with code formatting come from anywhere legitimate or is it an attempt to gain cheap rep?

Comment: Edit rejected..

Comment: [These editors](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/242018) apprenticed under the same master.

Comment: The unnecessary backticks thing seems to be some sort of cultural thing or something and I want to strangle everyone involved (in a non-murder-related way, of course)

Comment: @All: Ach, sorry, I did search and didn't see anything similar. Thanks random♦

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the case. In that particular example, some of those changes are not useful("close button").

It can be useful to make a distinction between the general concept and the specific code entity when they have the same name. Are you talking about a input in general as a concept, or the `input` object in some language. This distinction can make the post more readable.

Comment: Disagree on `checkbox`. If it said `input` I might agree, but `checkbox` isn't an HTML entity or JavaScript type.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't the best example then, but I hope that the point still makes sense.

Comment: The point does make sense +1, and it depends on the language. There may in fact be a checkbox object in some other UI language. With that said, you could edit this answer to use "input" if you really wanted to ;)