# How can I use 'code blocks' for individual words?

Tags: support, markdown, code-block

I have seen users use code blocks

```
Such as this
```

in many posts, but in the middle of a sentence only on one word. I can't for the life of me figure out how they did it.

Surprisingly, I searched through Meta and couldn't find a similar question. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use `backticks` `

Comment: Wow, this whole time I saw that and had been just using apostrophes. Thank you for pointing out my ignorance.

Comment: See [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#code) for more info.

Comment: I remember having this same confusion when I was new here.  I had never heard of "backticks."

Comment: @jadarnel27 They're particularly cumbersome to use on an iPad. So much so that I often defer posting my comment/answer until I get back to a real keyboard.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've never tried, but now that you mention it, that's pretty terrible to do on my Android mobile device too.

Comment: Reminder: [don't use code spans for emphasis!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)

Comment: @user14155: Note that it's possible to view the source of existing posts using the `edit` link.

Answer (score 8):

You can get markdown help without having to come to meta by clicking the <kbd>?</kbd> while editing and then clicking on the [advanced help >>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link that appears right under it:

[image]

You can also click on the [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/138890/edit) link of any post that has formatting you wish to emulate, and see how it was done by reviewing the code behind the answer - which will show the markup/markdown used.

In this case you need to surround the string with the "back-tick" character (`) - for better directions see the other answers.

Comment: Edited my post to use links/kbd instead of code spans to keep @Shog9 happy. :-)

Comment: +1 for teaching him how to fish, but you could have also directly answered the question.

Comment: @JP he had already acknowledged that backticks are the answer in the comments on the question, so I didn't think that required repeating.

Answer (score 3):

Highlight the word and press <kbd>ctrl+K</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a "grave accent" and on most keyboards I've seen it is located next to the number 1, on the same key as the `tilde`:

[image: grave accent on keyboard]

Just surround the text with the accent mark to format it like a code block:

Hey how do you like `this`?

It works in comments as well!

Comment: [I have heard it both ways...](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=i've%20heard%20it%20both%20ways)