# Stricter <kbd> formatting; disallow JSFiddle links and other non-kbd content from the <kbd> tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, jsfiddle, kbd

Firstly, I've seen a few people using `<kbd>` tags to emphasise JSFiddle demo links, which goes against the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element):

> The kbd element represents user input (typically keyboard input, although it may also be used to represent other input, such as voice commands).

There are situations where `<kbd>` elements could have valid links, so there's no need to strip them out completely, but I can't ever see a need for a JSFiddle link within them.

<kbd>**[Look at my demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kxt5/)**</kbd>

Should JSFiddle links be blocked from `<kbd>` tags?

---

The other thing <kbd>is that there are currently no restrictions (or so it seems).
You can have an entire block of text within the `<kbd>` tags if you so desired.</kbd> which is silly.

You can also put images inside them, which seems a little unnecessary:

<kbd>[image: Woo hoo!]</kbd>

Does there need to be stricter formatting rules for the `<kbd>` tag to limit anything which shouldn't normally appear within them?

Comment: What is your feature request exactly? There's nothing in particular that you're suggesting... it's just a random "rant" about kbd.

Comment: I'm asking for stricter formatting rules for the `<kbd>` tag. I figured that would be obvious, but let me edit it into my question.

Comment: Can you provide some examples where these problems appear in the wild?

Comment: What if I have a potato-button on my keyboard?

Comment: @EmilVikström Well here's a question I just edited on SO which placed JSFiddle link within the `<kbd>` tags, which sparked this post: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15882334/1. The rest is just a result of toying with the `<kbd>` tag to see if SO imposed any restrictions.

Comment: Your examples are abuse of the formatting, [just like unnecessary code tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right), or everything in bold...and so on. Just edit it out.

Comment: Sulfurized Demonbobby, I have two upvote-buttons on my keyboard!

Comment: You must be rich man. In Latvia we dream about keyboard potato.

Comment: @EmilVikström: Then you're one lucky bastard, I only have one button which casts downvotes *with extreme prejudice*. ;)

Comment: @Balpha that has to be the fastest `status-declined` I've ever seen.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII [7:18](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/140200/revisions), [6:14](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/139969/revisions) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dislike formatting abuse as much as the next guy, but this isn't something you should enforce technically. What if people want to legitimately link a `<kbd>` tag? For example I coult tell you to read all about <kbd>[Scroll Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_lock)</kbd> :)

Unless this really becomes a wide-spread problem – which I doubt –, editing them out and educating the posters to please not do that seems good enough.

Comment: This is why I mentioned filtering just JSFiddle links. I can't imagine a situation where a `<kbd>` tag would be the only way of displaying a link to such an example. "[Here's a demo](http://example.com) (press <kbd>A+B+C</kbd>)" over "Here's a demo: <kbd>[A+B+C](http://example.com)</kbd>"

Comment: @JamesDonnelly the thing about `<kbd>` is that it's not an obvious feature. It's not in the toolbar, and your n00b who is just joining the site simply won't know about it.