# Why is my avatar picture showing up blank?

Tags: support, profile-picture

Lately, my avatar picture is not showing up. Instead, I get a grey box. I've even tried making a physically smaller image (256x256) and uploading that in its place, but it's still not showing up. Could the fact that it's in GIF format be the problem? I'm also behind a corporate firewall. Could that be part of the problem?

Here's a screen shot of what I'm seeing:

> [image: blank avatar]

**Update:** I'm seeing other avatars, while others besides my own are blank (see screen shot), so it would seem that not all avatars are being hosted on imgur.com. This would seem to suggest that the problem can be solved on the site by not putting any avatars on imgur.com, where they would get blocked by corporate firewalls. (IMHO, *all* images should be hosted on a Stack Exchange URL, as not seeing them makes questions/answers that have images next to useless when seen from behind a corporate firewall that blocks imgur.com.)

> [image: one blank and one non-blank avatar]

Comment: Cartman flashing his buttocks looks normal enough

Comment: Seconded. It's showing up for others.

Comment: Are you sure you're pronouncing GIF correctly? Maybe that could be the problem

Comment: [GIF format, eh?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome)

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot, if it's still happening?

Comment: Your corporate firewall might indeed be blocking `imgur.com` domain or, if you can see other pictures, maybe blocking `.gif` pictures.

Comment: I can't see your avatar, but my corporate firewall blocks everything from imgur, including the non-gravatar profile pictures and any image added to a post.

Comment: Is it just your own avatar or do you not see anyone else's?

Answer (score 1):

No. The image is being displayed correctly on mine (and a [lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160599/hammar) [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/175875/dgund) users') browsers.

See your browser's image cache setting. Maybe you ran out of HDD space ;). As for the image being GIF, here is a PNG for you:

[image: Cartman]

Comment: So KBD has become the new backtick

Comment: @random [apparently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181774/212576)

Comment: Just uploaded a PNG version of my avatar, and I'm still not seeing it.