# What's the point of the Support tag if your question just ends up being closed as 'too localized'?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions, meta, reopen-closed

I posted [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182120/why-is-my-avatar-picture-showing-up-blank/182129?noredirect=1#182129) here on MSO yesterday asking for support on an issue that I'm having on on SO and MSO lately, and it ended up getting closed as being 'too localized' despite my use of the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag. First, how is my problem 'too local' when it's entirely possible that other people may experience the same problem? Second, shouldn't the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag be a cue that the OP is asking for support to solve a site related problem? If meta's not the appropriate place to seek support on site-related problems, then where is the appropriate place to go for that? If Meta is the appropriate place for support questions, then is there any way that I can get my question re-opened?

Comment: Why are you drawing a correlation here?

Comment: I see your avatar fine, and apparently a number of other folks did as well. Hence, "Too Localized". Closed is not a bad thing.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what do you think a 'closed'  question means?

Comment: Since only you can see not seeing your avatar and there is no screenshot to show otherwise, it's localised to you and your machine

Comment: I've added a screen shot and a mention that I'm behind a corporate firewall. @Andrew: What correlation are you seeing? My point is that, if I'm using the [tag:support] tag, shouldn't that be a cue that I'm asking for support from the people who are in charge of 'customer support' (for lack of a better term) for the site?

Comment: @RobH: Unfortunately if your corporate firewall is blocking Imgur and/or Gravatar, there's just not anything we can do for you. That's localized to you. Have you tried simply clearing your cache or a hard refresh? Maybe it was just a connection error, who knows.

Comment: @RobH the correlation the Andrew is mentioned is the fact that you seem to be indicating that [meta-tag:support] questions are always closed as `too-localized`.  There are 12,546 support question on MSO right now, and only 3,124 are closed, and I believe a good majority of them are duplicates and not too localized (but I don't have stats on that.

Comment: @RobH but the reason it was closed is you stated a couple of facts but didn't offer any info to help anyone solve your problem beyond stating "I'm behind a corporate firewall".  Now that you've added some more info, I voted to reopen your question, as has someone else.  But animuson is correct, if it is indeed all imgur.com images and it is just your corporate firewall, then it should be closed as too localized.

Comment: @psubsee2003: If the custom avatars are, indeed, imgur.com images, then this needs to be explained somewhere so that other people who are behind corporate firewalls that also block that particular site will know what's going on. (And, as corporate firewalls are common, then I submit that this issue is probably also happening to other people and is, therefore _not_ 'too local'.)

Comment: @RobH Related: [Hosting options for people that have Imgur blocked by their ISP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109975)

Comment: The fact that you think "this issue is probably also happening" doesn't make it so. If it was a common problem, I'd think there would be other questions here related to the issue (in which case it would be a duplicate). People behind corporate firewalls are most likely familiar with the problems that occur because of that, and figure out what the issue is without the need for support. For instance, I can, just like I figured out that when a question contains an image I can't see the image at work, so I have to use my smartphone or wait 'til I get home. :-)

Comment: Ok, but there still should be some kind of mention posted somewhere regarding where the custom avatars are stored (preferably in the documentation that describes that feature) so people can decide whether or not its even worth their while to have a custom avatar, because it came as a complete surprise to me that those would be hosted by imgur.com rather than Stack Exchange itself. (And in the long term, all images on the site should be moved to a URL that IT departments aren't going to be so quick to block.)

Comment: It's a good thing that we don't have "too localized" anymore...

Answer (score 2):

As explained [above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182203/whats-the-point-of-the-support-tag-if-your-question-just-ends-up-being-closed-a/182254#comment554773_182203) and in the [only answer you got](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182129/152998) the problem was restricted to your browser. The [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag is there to:

> [...] request help with the use of one of the Stack Exchange sites' features.

The fact that your browser cache is not displaying the image correctly is not a problem related to the Stack Exchange network therefore would never help anybody else.