# Don't make us click through the reject dialog on Suggested Edit audits

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

> #### tl;dr: Make the reject button in the suggested edit queue pass audits without a dialog.

I've reviewed over 700 suggested edits, so I have had my fair share of audits.

Unlike the other queues, suggested edit audits are, well, *obvious*. Random phrases inserted at random points - you *have* to be a robo-reviewer to not see them.

Also, the audit is passed if you reject with *any* reason - not just vandalism

So why are we making users click clear through the dialog? That's: 1 click for the Reject button, 1 click to choose a reason, another click to submit the reject, and another click to get past the audit-passed screen.

### That's **4** clicks.

On the other queues, it only takes one click minimum to pass an audit - usually a downvote.

Why don't we make the Reject button on audits automagically pass the audit? That would bring us down to **only 2** clicks - much better.

Comment: I like it, lazyness to the max while doing our civic duty. +1

Comment: @animuson No kbd tag? I thought I was being clever.

Comment: @Undo: The keyboard element is for semantically representing a *keyboard key*; it is not for buttons in general. ;P

Comment: @ani But it looks like a button :( You win.

Comment: @Undo: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules ;)

Comment: @animuson, no ["The `<kbd>` element represents user input"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-kbd-element), which in this case is a "Reject" *button*, which is a form of user input, and IMHO a valid use of the `kbd` element as per HTML5.

Comment: @zzzz I'm tempted to bounty you enough rep that you can fight Animuson through the rite of Edit Warring.

Comment: +1 for less clicks.  Less clicks = more time for waffles.

Comment: Not sure if you consider this close enough to be a duplicate: [Stop bothering me with suggested edit review audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182722/stop-bothering-me-with-suggested-edit-review-audits)

Comment: @Gilles I've read that one - it's about killing the 'woo-hoo, you didn't fail' screen. I agree with that (a *lot!*), but I want the close dialog to never happen with audits. Nice find, though.

Comment: The year is 2014. Robo-reviewers have taken over Stack Overflow, clicking Reject and checking for the dialog before accepting. All is chaos. Arbitrarily-`formatted` inline `code permeates` every question. The occasional question lands at the end of several answers. The sheer number of badges overflows the database. The internet goes dark, and with it, the world. Bright, blue sky becomes naught but a distant memory. People are afraid to go outside. You hide in your bed, wondering what could possibly have gone wrong so long ago. Then you wake up. It was all only a dream. You reach for the mouse.