# Making a visual button link in Stackoverflow for links

Tags: support, markdown, kbd

I often see people having html buttons for links in stack overflow?

how do I visually show a button on stack overflow
how do 
`<button><a href="www.jsfiddle.com">link to fiddle</a></button>`

Comment: Don't. That's invalid formatting and not what the syntax is there for. If you're still curious, it's the `<kbd>` element, which is reserved for **user input**, not for making links look like buttons.

Comment: Matthew Harwood, please don't do that as it was not meant to ;)

Answer (score 10):

Are you referring to this <kbd>[Click here](http://www.google.com)</kbd>?

`<kbd>[TEXT HERE](URL HERE)</kbd>`

However as recommended by animuson in a comment to your post, if you are intending to use this for links in a post, avoid doing so as it can be ambiguous to a user.  The  tag is to be used to showcase user input.  Users may not be aware that it is a clickable button.  try to always use the `[TEXT](URL)` tool to provide a hyperlink for the user.

Comment: Should I not uses this for links to jsfiddles?  like @animuson stated above?  Marking correct asap

Comment: Take the advice of Animuson very serious, please.

Comment: Please follow animuson's recommendation.  Reserve the use of this to showcase keyboard input; however, I have seen people use this to create buttons in their profiles.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood, yes, try to stay away from using it for external link. Just use a simple link using the `[text](URL)` tool.  It will also read better instead of having random buttons inserted in your text.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood See [Stricter <kbd> usage rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules/181795#181795)