# Setting bounty on an answered question

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, bounties

I have got this privilege of [start a bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) (never set a bounty myself for any question).

I understand starting a bounty for unanswered question is to get more attention to it but I really don't understand even if a question is answered it has this "start a bounty" displayed at the bottom of the question.

So my question is

- Why *start a bounty* is displayed below questions even if that question is answered?
- Can I start a bounty to increase the views and make my question more popular(even if it is answered)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: I dont find it duplicate.The questions asked in that page doesnt involve my questions.

Comment: @Zword please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right). Inline code is NOT for syntax highlighting.

Comment: I've seen bounties being used by people to reward answers that really helped them a lot. They may already have accepted the answer, but want to give a bonus to the person who helped them as well, so they create a bounty and give it immediately to that answer. It may even be a bounty given by someone other than the original poster, ie someone who found an existing answer that helped them so much that they wanted to give a reward. It happens.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am using inline code look to `start a bounty` because its similar to its actual look.

Comment: @Zword don't do that. Each place has its own rules, you will have to learn and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Start a bounty" is shown under all questions, even answered ones. The reason for this is that for certain topics at least, the answers may change over time. Only allowing bounties on un-answered questions would remove the ability to bring focus to a question in the instance where the answer expired or became no longer relevant.

Starting a bounty will make the question that has a bounty on it appear under [the "featured" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured), which can have the effect of driving more traffic to the question (since the question becomes one of a small number instead of one out of all questions asked with that tag or one question out of all of the questions on the site), which can have the side effect of increased voting and increased views on the question while promoting additional answers.

Bounties can be used for many reasons, including;

- driving traffic to a question (as above)
- be given to exceptional answers that you found particularly helpful as an additional reward
- get new answers or updated answers

There is no rule preventing you from putting a bounty on a question that already has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The option is there because the current answers might be

- very good and you want to reward them additional reputation
- outdated
- too narrow in scope
- unofficial, while you would like to get an answer from official sources, or
- overly broad containing too little detail.

The main point of a bounty is to get attention to both a question and its answers to get issues in them fixed or excellent answers' authors properly rewarded.