# Non-code text marked as code

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Why am I seeing people marking technical parts of texts (names of functions, files) a code (e.g. `` `explorer.exe` ``), while logically it is not a code? I agree that these things should be somehow highlighted, but I don't see the code marking an appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: @shadowwizard Not a strict duplicate, the pinned question discusses emphasis, while this one criticises using inline code for technical names and names with specific format.

Comment: Well, the answers in both are quite the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are totally right. Code formatting shouldn't be use for anything but code. It's the best to edit it out if you possibly can. (I can stretch the definition of 'code' to 'computer instruction', so file paths could be in it too, if correctly used).

To answer your question why people use it: I think most of them see it as a tool to emphasize some parts of the post. Others think everything should be code formatted and even format `the`.

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer to the [linked duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right) that code tags are also acceptable for "filenames, paths, API methods, commands, etc."

Comment: I can agree on that. In fact a file can be considered as computer instruction, so that would be in my definition of code.

Comment: @Thi: updated the answer.