# List of canonical answers for site/exchange-wide concerns?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

There are multiple answers on Meta that I believe should either be folded into a FAQ, or are of general-enough usefulness that they should show up for new users (askers or answerers). Little things like my answer regarding code highlighting https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135113/168933 or more important ones like link-only answers (like [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/168933) but there was a better one I can't find at the moment).

Is there a process for tidying up and subsequently moving those answers to a linkable FAQ section, or at the very least, a curated list of these references we can use when commenting on questions or answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The process goes through [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed), the wiki for which has fairly thorough instructions. But basically, a question must be edited (or composed fresh for the purpose) to have a sufficiently FAQ-y feel, the answers condensed to (ideally) a single clearly-applicable, correct, and thorough answer, and then SE employees put  [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on and add it to the [master index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). There's no particular timeline for this, and no one user needs to push through all the required moderation (especially to trim answers down to a singleton).

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.