# Does using code syntax for non-code content causes accessibility issues?

Tags: discussion, markdown, accessibility

I ask because I was told it does when I was working as web developer. On the other hand, diamond moderator who posted this: https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/19767/12008 insists on using this syntax and do not accept the fact that such issues can arise without a proof. I made him aware of [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/225745) but he just shrug it off as another matter and requests to know exact consequences...

So is using code format for emphasis on non-code content on Stack Exchange accessibility-safe, or no?

> let’s separate ‘it’s not semantic” from what are exact consequences

says [shabunc♦](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/242/shabunc) as a reason to ignore answers under [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/225745)

---

Edit: due to family situation I'm sort fused and tired around people who park on the spots reserved for wheelchair users and other people with mobility disabilities, and when asked argue instead of apologize and leave. Turns out I'm projecting it on analogous situations with other disabilities. Sorry I'm not sorry.

Comment: See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301372/295232) on the question you already linked to.

Comment: @Glorfindel Diamond on Russian stack says "let’s separate ‘it’s not semantic” from what are exact consequences".

Comment: That answer says: *Consider screen readers: if a visually impaired user configures their software to spell out code tags, or to have an easy keyboard shortcut with a macro called "jump to next code span/block and highlight" for easy copy-pasting, we are significantly disabling their ability to interact with the page. Further disabling, I should say.*

Comment: to whom it may concern - here's a dedicated post on Russian Meta - https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/454/implications-of-using-backtick-inline-code-markup-for-russian-text

Comment: I use a back tick for code inline with normal text—and also for formatting SE tags, like `discussion`,something I consider to be almost equivalent to code. But I don't use it anywhere else. To emphasize something, I always use italics or bold text. (Very occasionally I have used superscript or strikeout.)

Comment: Tags have a specific formatting, please use it instead of fudging other functionality when it is known to cause issues. [tag: discussion] without any spaces gives [tag:discussion]. @JasonBassford

Comment: @nij That look no different than an underlined hyperlink. I don't care about providing a hyperlink. If it weren't in a *comment* I would format it with the <kbd> tag.

Comment: @JasonBassford appropriate styles are applied in post bodies, just not in comments.